# Unable to mock assynchronous service behaviour with Rhyno mock

Tags: c#, silverlight, unit-testing, silverlight-4.0, rhino-mocks

I try to Mock (with Rhyno mock) the behaviour of a assynchronous service.

Here is an example: I got a service with one methode called void GetServerState(). As this method is assynchronous, it is void but when it's called, it'll call the proxies and the call an event GetServerStateCompleted(object,eventargs).
At this point I hope everybody still follow me ;-)

now, let have a look at the mock (wich is infact a stub, but never mind)

```
public class MyStub
{
 protected MockRepository MockRepository {get;set;}
 public IMyService MyService {get;set;} //the service with GetServerState() Method
 protected delegate void DelegateVoid(); //for easy writting

 public MyStub()
 {
   MockRepository = new MockRepository ();
   MyService = MockRepository.Stub<IMyService >();

   //And now, let's try to mock the behaviour
   MyService.Stub(sm => sm.GetServerState())
                .IgnoreArguments()
                .Do((DelegateVoid)GetServerStateCompletedBehaviour);
 }

 //the method that should be launched when someone call GetServerState on the Stub
 protected void GetServerStateCompletedBehaviour()
 {
  MyService.Raise(x=>x.GetServerStateCompleted+=null,MyService,new EventArgs());
 }
}

//And here is how I would like to use it
[TestMethod]
void Test()
{
 try
 {
  IMyService Stub = new MyStub().MyService;
  Stub += new EventHandler(EventMethod);
  Stub.GetServerState();
  Assert.Fail();
 }
 catch(MyException){}
}

void EventMethod(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Throw new MyException();
}
```

As everything seems right for me, this code doesn't work at all. Does someone has a begin of explanation for why it should not work ?

thx,

Answer (score 1):

I found what was wrong:

```
public MyStub()
 {
   MockRepository = new MockRepository ();
   //MyService = MockRepository.Stub<IMyService >(); //Stupid Stupid Stupid !!!
   MyService = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMyService >();

   //And now, let's try to mock the behaviour
   MyService.Stub(sm => sm.GetServerState())
                .IgnoreArguments()
                .Do((DelegateVoid)GetServerStateCompletedBehaviour);
 }
```